# Why the casting to byte in BufferedOutputStream works as not expected?

Tags: java

I'm writing a byte to the file `fileoutput.txt` using following code in Java:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/tests/fileoutput.txt");
BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

bos.write(153);
bos.flush();
```

To check what byte was saved in the text file I opened it in the hex editor. There I saw that the program writes the correct byte = 153 as expected.

But then I opened the sources of the write() method in the BufferedOutputStream class. This method takes the `int` in the argument and performs the casting from `int` to `byte`.

When the java makes this operation I expect that  the program returns the different byte, not similar to the original, because in the java the byte type has the maximum at 127. And when I perform the explicit cast `byte b=(int)153` the `b` field becomes equal to -103.

Why the `write()` method in the `BufferedOutputStream` class does the cast differently?

Comment: Casting an int to a byte just takes the 8 least significant bits out of the 32 bits constituting the integer. If you interpret these 8 bits as a signed integer number (i.e. using the first bit as a sign bit), you'll get a value between -128 and 127 (that's what Java does when it prints a byte, hence the printed value -103). If you interpret it as an unsigned integer number (that's what happens when printing the original int, since the 8th bit is not a sign bit in the case), you'll get a number between 0 and 255. -103 and 153 are just different representations of the same 8-bits binary value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary representation of 153 and -103 is the same. Therefore, the correct hex value ends up in the file.

Read up on two's complement for more info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement